# Compactness of a coarser topology than the usual in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

I am studying the properties of the following topology defined in $\mathbb{R}$:

$$T=\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R},\{(a,\infty)\}_{a\in\mathbb{R}}\}$$

As the usual topology is finer than this one and it is connected, I have already been able to say that $T$ is connected. However, with respect to wether it is compact or not I got stuck because I can't see it with the definition. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: The usual trick with the ordinary topology seems to work here.  Let the left endpoint expand to get an open cover.  No finite subcollection would work, though.

Comment: Is the identity $(\Bbb R,T)\to\Bbb R$ continuous? What does that suggest about compactness?

Comment: Ok, alright, now I see clearly it is not compact (both with Randall's idea and the fact compactness is preserved by continuous functions as FShrike suggested). But then I can also state it is not countably compact or sequentally compact because it is metrizable,right??

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to change the goals of your question after it's been answered. Sequential compactness is equivalent to compactness for metric spaces, but what's your metric?

Comment: My apologies for that. I wasn't aware of it. Yes, it's true it is not metrizable (I wrongly thought because it's coarser than a metrizable it must be)

Answer (score 2):

The collection
$$
\big\{ (a, +\infty) \colon a \in \mathbb{R} \big\}
$$
is an open covering of $\mathbb{R}$, and this collection has no finite subcollection that could cover $\mathbb{R}$. So this topological space is not compact.

PS:

> This space is not sequentially compact, for the sequence $\left( n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, for example, has no subsequence converging to a point of this space.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Saaqib Mahmood, and what about sequentally compactness and countably compactness?

Comment: @CharlesJA please have a look at the PS I've just added.

Comment: The  first part of this answer is right, but the sequence $(n)$ actually converges to every point of $\mathbb R$. A counterexample to sequential compactness is $(-n)$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I stand corrected. Thank you.